# ASP.NET: Importing Csv into SQL server 2008 using INSERT INTO

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, csv

I'm working on an MVC4 project and I stumbled across this problem. I've tried looking for an answer, but no existing answer seems to suit my needs.

Here's the problem: I'm having an SQL table (let's call it TestTable), which has the following columns:
- Id (PK)
- Name (NOT NULL)
- Address
- City
- Postal Code
- Facebook
- Twitter
- Initiatives
- Votes
- Actions
...

And I have a .csv with the following columns:
- name
- initiatives_no
- number_of_votes
- number_of_actions

The Id's and names are imported into the TestTable once, using the import wizard that comes with the SQL Server Management Studio. The csv has to be imported on a regular basis, containing more up-to-date data.

Now here's the problem: I don't know how I have to import the data from the .csv to the TestTable, without creating a new table row.

I don't know if the syntax is completely right, but I want to do something like this:

INSERT INTO TestTable(Initiatives, Votes, Actions) 
VALUES (initiatives_no, number_of_votes, number_of_actions) WHERE TO_UPPER(TestTable.Name) == TO_UPPER(Name) //import a row where the csv-name column equals the TestTable-name column

I'm stuck on this problem for a while now, and I definitely could use some help :)
Thanks

Comment: sounds like you want to be using the SQL [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx) command rather than INSERT! (going off what you said rather than your pseudo-sql)

Comment: I've never read anything about MERGE anywhere, so I had no idea of its existence.. But at first look, this seems to be the thing I need ideed.. Thanks for the good interpretation of bad pseudo-sql ^^

Answer (score 0):

So you need to do an update rather than an insert to the test table? Use a staging table to which you import the csv. Then perform an update join between the two tables. This is ok for an ad-hoc solution. If you need to incorporate it into your project then read the file to memory and iterate over each row and perform the update join for each row. Let me know if this helps

Comment: Merge would also work perfectly as James suggests. It's useful where there are new rows in your csv file that you want to include in your table as new rows. Otherwise update join would suffice.

Comment: Right now, I'm making a DataTable, using the csv-file.
How can I use this table to perform an update-join? I think this solution would suffice, because there are no new rows to be imported with that csv file (every name already exists in the database, so the information of the csv would be imported into existing rows in the TestTable).

Comment: For each r as datarow in datatable.rows. Inside the loop use the item property on r and pass these to a stored proc that performs the update join.

Answer (score 0):

Try with BULK INSERT, this is faster than anything else:

```
    BULK INSERT
        'YOUR_TABLE'
    FROM 
        'C:\ALL_THE_DATA.txt'
    WITH (
        FIELDTERMINATOR= '\t',
        ROWTERMINATOR = '\n' 
    );
```

There's something you need to do when the columns are in a different order, check [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187833.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the sql server's tool.

I suggest you to use " Navicat for SQL Server " to do the import job.